# Spacemacs packages disapear on reboot

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

Whenever I boot up emacs the packages that I installed on the previous session disapear and I have to reinstall them. I run this command to allow multiple terminals, if I close emacs and reopen it, this package and all others will have to be reinstalled.

```
package-install multi-term
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate...

Comment: What version of Emacs are you using? What value does `package-user-dir` have, and does that directory appear to contain packages in their own directories (e.g. `multi-term-1.2/`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out because I was using Spacemacs for emacs, the dotspacemacs file that it uses for all its configurations and packages overwrites the emacs.d file. This causes the packages installed using:

```
package-install
```

to become orphaned and they get removed on reboot.

To solve this I had to manually add the packages to the dotspacemacs-additional-packages function. This tells spacemacs on bootup to install/load those packages. When ever you add a new package add it here rather than using the package-install command.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `package-initialize`. You will probably want to add it to your init file and read its documentation about other applicable settings, eg. <kbd>M-x</kbd>`describe-function` `package-initialize`

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix the problem. I ran that function before I quit emacs and after I reopened it and I still don't have the packages

Comment: Check if your init file (or custom file, if you've set it)  has the list of packages that you've installed. Emacs should create that list when packages are added.

Comment: It is becuse im using spacemacs and you have to manually add them to your dotspacemacs file otherwise they are deemed orphans and get deleted, thanks for the help it works now